# Float objects are not visualized if they are forced in a specific position

Tags: floats, subfloats, acm

I am using the ACM template, in particular, the sig-conference one. I am trying to push a wide figure in a specific position:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \subfloat[\]{}\qquad
    \subfloat[\]{\}]
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:timeresult}
\end{figure*}
```

However, if I use the H parameter the figure does not show up in the final pdf.

```
\begin{figure*}[H]
    \subfloat[\]{}\qquad
    \subfloat[\]{\}]
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:timeresult}
\end{figure*}
```

Any advice?

Comment: We would need a full but minimal, compilable document (MWE) which causes this issue. Also note that forcing float position is considered bad practise. (It's a *float*, not a *static*).

Comment: Please also have a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned). Float placement is a #1 issue with LaTeX beginners.

Comment: The problem is that latex is putting one my table and one of my figure after a figure that comes after in the document. Using ACM template does not help the float positioning. @MartinScharrer

Comment: you can not use `H` with `figure*` (what would you want it to mean?)  `figure*` means to span the figure at the top of the page over both columns,  so you can not use `h` and definitely not `H` You need to allow it to move to the top of the next page.

Comment: figures will be kept in order. If latex is allowing the `figure*` to appear out of sequence with a single column `figure` then you must have an old version of latex (older than 2015)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried for hours, but I could not find an explanation or solution.
%
Using `[H]` is not a good solution because it tells LaTeX to treat the figure/table/etc. as a non-float, forcing it to place in the exact declaration position. However, this often leads to weird section breaks, making you lose a lot of space.

It turns out the ACM template loads many packages, and some might conflict with the ones you loaded.

In my case, I had used `\usepackage{nidanfloat}` for fixing my floats position with an IEEE template. By removing this package, the ACM template places the floats normally for me when using `\documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}`